# Java classes and subclasses logic

Tags: java, logic, structure

I'm learning about Java classes and this example came on my mind:

Let's say I'm developing an app that can create cars. Each car is made up of some components (engine, tires, ...) and each component gives the car a boost in some areas (for example the engine boosts the acceleration).

To develop this I thought I can build a class "Cars" which has some variables that hold which components that car is equipped with. Then I create a base class "Components" which holds the characteristic common to all components (their weight, size, ...) and some generic functions. Then I create some subclasses of the "Components" class which define a specific component (for example I create the class "Engines" or "Tires").
Of course each engine can be of different brands (BMW, Audi, ...) and each brand has different characteristics (let's say Audi engines accelerate faster than BMW ones).

Now the question is, do I have to create different subclasses for each brand engine? Of course I can, but **is this the correct way to build these kinds of "structures"?**

And for example, if, after I build all the classes, I notice that I have to add another characteristic to all engine (for example maximum speed) I have to change all the subclasses of each specific brand engine, but this doesn't sound very "efficient".

Comment: You need to decide if there's something inherent about being a "BMW" or "Audi" engine that is inherent (this engine **is-a** `BMW`), or if the brand is just a piece of data (this engine **has-a** brand, whose value is `"BMW"`).  Which way you go depends on what you want your app to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference can be expressed with different values of one same data attribute, and does *not* require different code paths to process those values, then you don't need separate subclasses for them.

For instance, if you are calculating 0-60, you would have a generic formula, to which you plugin a particular engine's acceleration parameters. There is no need for separate `AudiEngine` and `BMWEngine` classes.

OTOH, if an Audi engine has the additional feature of making a car invisible, then you do need a special `AudiEngine` class, with a special `enableInvisibility()` method on it.

Rule of thumb: if you find yourself writing `if/else` blocks that check on object types and do different things accordingly, you need subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me to understand more about the logic behind classes. However, as I said in another comment: "Now, I think that all the engines has charateristics such as power or acceleration, but, following my example, an Audi engine can have an extra feature (for example "reduce fuel consumption") and a BMW engine can have another typical feature. I thought I can write these feature functions in another class "Functions", and then I can create a new parameter in "Engines" class which hold a sort of unique code related to the extra feature each engine has" [...]

Comment: [...] I thought about this because sometimes a class has a lot of data and function that can be used in subclasses which differ just for one/few specific function/s, and maybe creating such similiar classes makes the structure of the code less easy to understand/mantain.

Comment: Is "reduce fuel consumption" an actual feature, i.e. something you can "invoke", or just some positive characteristics, i.e. less `gasMileage` than other engines?

Comment: It is something I can invoke. Your example "enableInvisibility" was definetly better.

Answer (score 1):

you're on the right track but you're running into decisions that all designers face and there is no clear answer.

but to expand you could specifically define `behaviours`.. for example, you could start with your base class `car`. then you could define an interface such as:

```
interface driveable
{
     void drive(engine type_of_engine, tire type_of_tire);
}

interface moddable
{
    void tune(exhuast type_of_exhaust);
}
```

then with `car`:

```
class car : driveable
{
    void drive(...)
}

class bmw : car {...}
class audi : car, moddable {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like your example because I find it very modular. Of course I'm not developing an app such as the one I described, I'm just trying to understand a "logic" for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

The "rule of thumb" is: you need separate classes if there is different *behavior*.

eg.: An engine has a different *behavior* than a *Tire*, but a *Audi engine* has the same behavior as a *BMW engine*, just the *property* "amount of acceleration" differs, which is a *configuration*, not behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep in mind your "rule of thumb", I'm quite new to programming and I'm self-learning, so I find rules like this very useful.

Comment: Now, I think that all the engines has charateristics such as power or acceleration, but, following my example, an Audi engine can have an extra feature (for example "reduce fuel consumption") and a BMW engine can have another typical feature. I thought I can write these feature functions in another class "Functions", and then I can create a new parameter in "Engines" class which hold a sort of unique code related to the extra feature each engine has. Is this a good way to do this? Or is it better to create a class for each specific engine, and there write the extra feature function?

Comment: No. Any engine consums fule. How much is again an configuration. A different behavior would be if the relationship between gas input and rotation speed would be linear for one engine type and exponential for another.

Comment: Ok, in the case of the fluid consumption I can use a linear relation, but it was just an example. I mean a feature specific of an engine, so a "behaviour"

Comment: Any engine does one thing: it consumes gas (or electricity) to produce heat and rotation. There is no room for "features". Therefore an Engine is a bad example at all.

Comment: Yes, an engine doesn't seem to be a good example. However let's say these are magical engines, so for example the Audi engine can make the whole car invisible and the BMW one can make it 2x bigger. These are behaviours, so in this case is it a good strategy to give these behaviours a "unique code" (as I said in the preview comment), or is it better create different classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use polymorphism and inheritance. For example, you create a class of slinics - each has the same variables (brand, power, etc.). Then, when calling the class constructors, you can initialize variables (assign them "BMW", 130 etc.)
It all depends on how your application works.
If this is not the answer you want, specify the question and I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that if I do so I assign the brand name value to a String parameter of the class. This of course is a way to obtain the result I want, but I don't know if it is the best choice. Of course it also depends on the purpose of the application.